# How to pass variables to parallel command

Tags: gnu-parallel

How do I pass different values to a single `parallel` command:

I tried this:

```sh
parallel ::: 'X="aa"' 'X="bb"' ::: echo ${X}
```

which only prints two empty lines, as if the value of `X` is not set.
I tried with `echo $X` with the same result.

I expected it to print

```
aa
bb
```

as if I had run sequentially:

```sh
echo "aa"
echo "bb"
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you actually want to do. Can you please show the first 4-5 commands you want to run, just one after the other without using `parallel` please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell , thanks, see the edit. `echo "aa"; echo "bb"`. This is just a minimal example of a case in which I have to run many times the same command with slighly different options.

Comment: `parallel ::: "aa" "bb"` maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, do you mean `parallel echo ::: "aa" "bb"`? yes, that does the trick but I want to pass variables since in the real case I need to options (and several of them) that are in the middle of the commands.

Comment: Ok, so please show the first 4-5 commands you actually want to run so I can see the pattern and how you use variables.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, it is in the edit. I want the same effect as in `echo "aa"; echo "bb"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you want run.

You clearly do not want:

```
X="aa" echo ${X}
X="bb" echo ${X}
```

because that outputs nothing.

Do you want:

```
X="aa"; echo ${X}
X="bb"; echo ${X}
```

In that case you can do one of:

```
parallel ::: 'X="aa";' 'X="bb";' ::: 'echo ${X}'
parallel {1}\;{2} ::: 'X="aa"' 'X="bb"' ::: 'echo ${X}'
parallel '{}; echo ${X}' ::: 'X="aa"' 'X="bb"'
```

However, the GNU Parallel way to do it would be to use the GNU Parallel replacement strings instead of $X:

```
parallel echo {} ::: aa bb
```

So if you want to run:

```
CXX="c++"; ID="c++"; cd ${ID}; ${CXX} main.cpp
CXX="/local/bin/nvcc"; ID="nvcc"; cd ${ID}; ${CXX} main.cpp
```

You would use :::+ :

```
parallel 'cd {2}; {1} main.cpp' ::: c++ /local/bin/nvcc :::+ c++ nvcc
```

Also: `--dry-run` is your friend, as it will show you what would be run, and that can often help understand the effect.

If you are new to GNU Parallel and prefer reading a book, buy GNU Parallel 2018 at http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html or download it at: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014

Read at least chapter 1+2. It should take you less than 20 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the `;` but you interpreted the goal right. The reason I couldn't use the usual idiom is because I needed to set pairs of variables in parallel. Something like, `parallel ::: 'CXX="c++"; ID="c++";' 'CXX="/local/bin/nvcc"; ID="nvcc"' ::: 'cd ${ID}; ${CXX} main.cpp'`. Thank you for this great tool. This tools make the impossible possible.